# Is Google api limit based on ip or page ? client side scripting avoid limit crossing?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my server i am using some function to find out pickup and drop lat and lang , direction from google map api services,so limit is crossed some days so i have desiede to go with user side scripting to calculate all google api service using following code this will help me ?

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="geolocate1()">
    <input type="text" id="pickup"  onFocus="geolocate()" placeholder="Enter your pick up place" />
 <input type="text" id="plat" value=""  id="plat"/>
 <input type="text" id="plang" value="" id="plang"/>
 <input type="text" id="pstatuslat" value="error" />
 <input type="text" id="km"  />
 </br>
    
  </br>
    <input type="text" id="drop" onFocus="geolocate1()" placeholder="Enter your Drop off place"/>
 <input type="text" id="dlat" value=""  id="plat"/>
 <input type="text" id="dlang" value="" id="plang"/>
 <input type="text" id="dstatuslat" value="error" />

    <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
  <input type="button" onclick="GetLocation1();GetLocation();calcRoute();" value="Book Now" />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=places"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function GetLocation() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById("pickup").value;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    document.getElementById('plang').value= longitude; 
                    document.getElementById('plat').value= latitude; 
                    document.getElementById('pstatuslat').value= "ok"; 
                } else {
                      document.getElementById('pstatuslat').value= "error"; 
                }
            });
        };
  
   function GetLocation1() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById("drop").value;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    document.getElementById('dlang').value= longitude; 
                    document.getElementById('dlat').value= latitude; 
                    document.getElementById('dstatuslat').value= "ok"; 
                } else {
                      document.getElementById('dstatuslat').value= "error"; 
                }
            });
        };
        //-->

// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var autocomplete;

function geolocate1() {

// Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
var input = document.getElementById('pickup');
var options = {types: ["geocode"],componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
// When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
// populate the address fields in the form.
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
fillInAddress();
});
}
function geolocate() {
// Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
// to geographical location types.
var input = document.getElementById('drop');
var options = {types: ["geocode"],componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
// When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
// populate the address fields in the form.
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
fillInAddress();
});
}

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('pickup').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('drop').value;

  var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var route = response.routes[0];
    var km = parseFloat(route.legs[0].distance.text.replace(" km", ""));

    document.getElementById('km').value =  km * 0.6214;
      }
    
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google API is limited with your Key using. Doesnt matter, if you have the same IP or different, each call to the Google API with you registered Key will be counted.

F.e. using Google Elevation API is limited for 2500 calls each day, doesnt matter, who is calling this, its limited to you API Key.

Comment: api key not problem i will get but with out that the service is fine ?